# Action not allowed

Tags: google-apps-script

I have written a script with the admin session. When I run it on this session it's all right. However, when someone from my organization runs it, there is an error message : `"Action not allowed"` even if I authorized the popup to run the script. Here is the script :

```
function AddToList(){

  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var response = ui.prompt('Ajout d\'un intervenant :', "Prénom NOM", ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  var nom = response.getResponseText();
  var ligne = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID).getSheetByName("Liste intervenant").getLastRow()
  if (response.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.YES) { 
    ssList.getRange(ligne+1,1).setValue(nom)
    main(nom)
  }

}
```

Does anyone have an idea ?

Comment: Could you clarify two things? (1) Is this line correct? `{ ssList.getRange(ligne+1,1).setValue(nom) main(nom) }`  (2) Is the ssID defined for use in `SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID)`?

Comment: Hello! just like @ADW mentioned, would you mind going through the `{ ssList.getRange(ligne+1,1).setValue(nom) main(nom) ` line again? Also, did the other users grant the necessary permissions? Cheers!